# ERRR: Cannot find free port for /168.2.4.54 from baseport = 54321

Tags: linux, hadoop, h2o

I was running H2O on Hardoop when this error occured.
This is the doc of how to install and running H2O on Hardoop:
[image]

1. First, I download H2O for my version of Hadoop.
2. Then I unpack the zip file and run this command

hadoop jar h2odriver.jar -nodes 1 -mapperXmx 6g -output /user/root/lyh2/h2o_output

3. But the console shows error info:

ERRR: Cannot find free port for /168.2.4.54 from baseport = 54321
EmbeddedH2OConfig: exit called (-1)
EmbeddedH2OConfig: after bwt.start()

4. I check the port 54321, no other application is using it.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The relevant message is coming from here:

- https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-core/src/main/java/water/init/NetworkInit.java#L121

This is a very unusual message/error.

Each H2O node tries to open a port for the embedded HTTP server.  The first attempted port is the baseport, and if that fails, then H2O tries increasing the number in a loop until it goes past port number 64K and then gives up with the message you reported.

You will have to ask your system admin why ports cannot be opened.

Note you can change the starting baseport with the `-baseport` option.

Comment: I run a tomcat to check the port, and it haven't been taken. But I just can't run H2O successfully.